# Can't upload image to website with PHP and MySQL

Tags: php

```
<?php


    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $title = $_POST['title'];

        if (isset($_FILES['images']['name'])) {
            $image_name = $_FILES['images']['name'];
            echo($image_name);
            $image_path = $_FILES['images']['tmp_name'];
            echo($image_path);
            $destination_path = 'location:'.SITEURL.'images/category/'.$image_name;
            // echo($destination_path);
            $upload = move_uploaded_file($image_name, $destination_path);
            echo($upload);

            if ($upload==0) {
                $_SESSION['upload_image_category'] = "<div class='error'>failed to upload image </div>";
                header('location:'.SITEURL.'admin/add-category.php');
                die();
            }
        }
        else{
            $image_name = "";
        }

        if (isset($_POST['featureyon'])) {
            $feature = $_POST['featureyon'];
        }
        else{
            $feature = "No";
        }

        if (isset($_POST['a_yes'])) {
            $active = $_POST['a_yes'];
        }
        else{
            $active = "No";
        }
        
        # code...
        $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_category SET 
            title = '$title',
            image_name='$image_name', 
            featured='$feature', 
            active='$active'
        ";
        $res = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        if ($res == True) {
            $_SESSION['add_category'] =  "<div class='success'>New category added</div>";
            header('location:'.SITEURL.'admin/manage_category.php');
        }
        else{
            $_SESSION['add_category'] = "<div class='error'>failed to add New category </div>";
            header('location:'.SITEURL.'admin/add-category.php');
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Please provide more information as to what exactly is or isn't happening and when. Let us know what you have tried.

Comment: Why do you have `location:` in `$destination_path`? That's not part of the pathname.

Comment: What did your [**PHP error logs**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127838/where-does-php-store-the-error-log-php-5-apache-fastcgi-and-cpanel?noredirect=1&lq=1) tell you?

Comment: `$destination_path` should be a real pathname on the server, not a URL.

Comment: when try to upload image i get this error **if ($upload==0) {
                $_SESSION['upload_image_category'] = "<div class='error'>failed to upload image </div>";
                header('location:'.SITEURL.'admin/add-category.php');
                die();
            }**  failed to upload image

Comment: Ok, so that means `move_uploaded_file` returned false. Now you need to trace back again to work out why that might have happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**the first**

$destination_path should be a real pathname on the server, not a URL. Like this :- $destination_path = '../images/category/'.$image_name;

**the second**

move_uploaded_file(source_path, destination_path) Like this :-
$upload = move_uploaded_file($image_path, $destination_path);